# pass data to constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I’m having a weird & frustrating problem passing an object between some of my classes. This stems from the fact I am a scripter and not a programmer, and am just bumbling along. So I’m sure I’m doing something dumb :)

I am trying to build a Wizard dialog which has multiple pages. I am using the “Internationalised WPF Wizard” tutorial from CodeProject as a starting point, and attempting to adapt it to my domain. I’m getting stuck because my wizard pages can’t seem to refer to the model.

I have done the following:

- Created a class for my Model (let call this MyData)
- Created a base class for my view models (ViewModelBase)
- Created a view model class for each of my pages, inheriting from ViewModelBase (example below is WelcomePageViewModel)
- Created a ‘controller’ style view model which drives the wizard. (WizardController)

When the wizard is launched, WizardController is instantiated. WizardController also instantiates MyData.Then, WizardController instantiates each of the view models for the remaining pages.

The actual GUI seems to work fine, and I can see that the view models for each of the pages are being loaded correctly. Here’s some code:

```
public class MyData
{
    private string _someString;
    public MyData(string someString)
    {
        _someString = someString;
    }
}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _isCurrentPage;
    readonly MyData _myData;
    public ViewModelBase(MyData myData)
    {
        _myData = myData;
    }
}

public class WizardController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    MyData _myData;
    public WizardController()
    {

        _myData = new MyData("The Widgets");
    }
}


public class WelcomePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyData _myData;

    public WelcomePageViewModel(MyData myData)
        : base(myData)
    {
        _myData = myData;
        // accessing _myData fails :(
        MyLogger.WriteLine("Grabbed an instance of myData: " + _myData.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, my code fails when I try to access myData from WelcomePageViewModel. On the MyLogger line in WelcomePageViewModel, the error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.” is thrown.

Basically, all I’m trying to achieve is WizardController setting up MyData, and each of the wizard pages being able to access (and manipulate) it. So any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the code that accesses the `WelcomePageViewModel` object?  Where is the `WelcomePageViewModel` stored?

Comment: If you're declaring it in the abstract class, why are you then redeclaring it in the actual implemented classes? Also, you'll want it to be protected instead of private, if you want to access it in an inheriting class. If you need to override it, use the virtual and override keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rob G suggested in a comment, you're re-declaring the variable _myData in the inherited classes. The correct way to organize your code is to let the _myData be a protected property declared only on the abstract base class, and use this property to access the variable from the inheriting classes.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _isCurrentPage;

    protected MyData MyData { get; private set; }

    public ViewModelBase(MyData myData)
    {
        MyData = myData;
    }
}

public class WelcomePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{  
    public WelcomePageViewModel(MyData myData)
        : base(myData)
    {
       // Access the protected property
       MyLogger.WriteLine("Grabbed an instance of myData: " + MyData.ToString());
    }
}
```

Edit: fixed a copy-paste error...

Comment: Thank you havardhu! That was spot on!